# Configure Apache to route "GET /user/foo" to /user/GET.php and "PUT /user/foo" to /user/PUT.php

Tags: apache, http, rest, routes, scripting

I would like to arrange things so that a GET request for e.g.

```
http://example.com/user/foo@bar.com
```

internally calls the script

```
/var/www/example.com/rest/user/GET.php
```

and a PUT request for the same URL internally calls the script

```
/var/www/example.com/rest/user/PUT.php
```

and so on for the other HTTP verbs POST and DELETE.

It's almost possible to achieve this via the [<Script>](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_actions.html#script) directive, but it doesn't quite work, because "[Script with a method of GET will only be called if there are query arguments present](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_actions.html#script)".  This means that if Apache is configured via

```
<Location /user>
Script GET /rest/user/GET.php
Script PUT /rest/user/PUT.php
</Location>
```

then, whilst a GET request for

```
http://example.com/user/foo@bar.com?foo=bar
```

will call `GET.php`, if the request does not contain the query string "foo=bar", it doesn't.

(Also, why was `<Script>` designed like this in the first place?)

Answer (score 2):

You could use mod_rewrite making use of a `RewriteCond` on `REQUEST_METHOD`

e.g.:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_METHOD} ^GET$
```

Comment: I actually tried a mod_rewrite solution first, but that failed for other reasons (something went wrong in ScriptAlias and/or the FastCGI-powered PHP) that seemed more difficult to solve... If you do have this working, can you post your Apache conf?